# how can I fix this issue , I want to create array of album

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is the Error that show after I hover the album attribute which show up in red
I have tried to trace this problem by going the the AlbumCategory->index.tsx file but I keep getting the same error I have try everything  but to no avail please help and thank you in advanced

```
 Type '{ id: string; imageUri: string; artistsHeadline: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '[Album]'.
      Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)
    index.tsx(8, 5): The expected type comes from property 'albums' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AlbumCategoryProp'
```

[image]

here is the  HomeScreen.tsx file code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import EditScreenInfo from '../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';
import AlbumCategory from '../components/AlbumCategory';

const albumCategory = {
  id: '1',
  title: 'Trap-Co',
  ablums:[
    {
      id: '1',
      imageUri: 'https://cache.boston.com/resize/bonzai-fba/Globe_Photo/2011/04/14/1302796985_4480/539w.jpg',
      artistsHeadline: 'Taylor Swift, Kygo Objective C, Avicii'
    }

  ]
};

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AlbumCategory  title={albumCategory.title} albums={albumCategory.ablums} />//this the error

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: '80%',
  },
});
```

Here is the AlbumCategory->index.tsx file code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Album } from '../../types'
import styles from './styles';
export type AlbumCategoryProp = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    albums: [Album],
}


const AlbumCategory = function (props: AlbumCategoryProp): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default AlbumCategory;
```

Here is the type.tsx file code

```
export type Album = {
  id: string;
  imageUri: string;
  artistsHeadline: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `AlbumCategoryProp` definition you seem to have a typo.  This is not an array of albums:

```
albums: [Album],
```

I'm *guessing* instead it's being interpreted as an array (of any type) which contains exactly one `Album`, and the array you're passing it doesn't guarantee that.

This would be a simple array of albums:

```
albums: Album[];
```

Comment: this did not work it will produce a error

Comment: @GeorgeSMulbahII: And what is that error?  Which line produces it?

Comment: you are correct I had a typo with the semicolon

Answer (score 1):

I think You Should TRY:

```
albums:Album[];
```

Comment: this did not is there any other suggestion you have